# Sklearn - normalize array with MinMaxScaler

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to normalize some data between 0 and 1 using sklearn library:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

data = np.array([
        [10, 20, 30],
        [400, -2, 60],
        [5, 80, 90]
    ])
```

I'm trying to find the value for the **second line**, with:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
print(scaler.fit(data))
print(scaler.transform(data))
```

But I'm being told that the result `[1.         0.         0.5       ]` is wrong:

```
MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0, 1))
[400.  80.  90.]
[[0.01265823 0.26829268 0.        ]
 [1.         0.         0.5       ]
 [0.         1.         1.        ]]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The scaling is performed on the `numpy.array` columns, so it appears correct, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MimMaxScaler` expects input as `(n_samples, n_features)`, and it tries to scale features (so, it perform scaling on columns of your data).

For `[1. 0. 0.5]`, the array calculated like this:

```
(400-5) / (400-5) = 1.     #first column
(-2+2)  / (80+2)  = 0.     #second column
(60-30) / (90-30) = 0.5    #third column
```